# session not being destroyed after update is complete

Tags: php, session

I have a page that uses sessions, on this page I want to be able to update text in fields and then update the DB with that text.  This all works fine, however after the update is complete the session is not being destroyed so when I go back to the display page, if I try to click on another entry I get the results from the previous session.  For example, I click on a button to update a project that has a pId of 3 and update pDesc, pId 3 is updated properly.  Now I want to updated pId 4, I am still getting pId 3 info populated in the various boxes and no info from pId 4.  Any advice on how to get this to work?

This is BEdisplay that display a list of projects(I have not included all the code):

```
session_start();

try {
//SQL SELECT statement
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM projecttable");
$result->execute();
// assign returned array elements to variables
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "Table Retrieval Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Back End Insert</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
</head>
<body>
<br>
<h1>Project Dashboard</h1>
<form action="index.php">
<button class="buttonAdd" type="submit" name="add">Add Project</button>
</form>

<?php
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $pId = $row['pId'];
    $pName = $row['pName'];
    $pDesc = $row['pDesc'];
    $dDate = $row['dDate'];

    $_SESSION['pId'] = $pId;
    $_SESSION['pName'] = $pName;
    $_SESSION['pDesc'] = $pDesc;
    $_SESSION['dDate'] = $dDate;
    ?>
```

This is process.php which uses a switch case to determine which action to take:

```
switch ($action) {

case 'delete' :
    echo $pId;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM projecttable WHERE pId  = '$pId'";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    header("Location: BEdisplay.php");
    break;

case 'update' :
    header("Location: update.php");
    break;
}
```

Here is where I get the session info from update.php:

```
session_start();
$pId = $_SESSION['pId'];
$pName = $_SESSION['pName'];
$pDesc = $_SESSION['pDesc'];
$dDate = $_SESSION['dDate'];
session_unset();
session_destroy();
```

When an update button is pressed we go to updateSQL.php where an update is run then back to BEdisplay.php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same code in your BEdisplay.php file to unset/destroy the session as you did for your update.php file. That's why it's not getting unset/destroyed.

Note: I have to state that your code is open to an sql injection, use a prepared statement.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Check for errors on both the PHP and the query (just in case):

- https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- https://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

and use `var_dump();` https://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: thanks I will update my code to prevent SQL injections.  When i add unset() and destroy() to BEdisplay, and press update the session variables are not being carried to the next page now.

Comment: @Kip242 I added a few more reference links, reload the answer. Could also be a caching issue. Reload the pages/hard refresh them.

Comment: @Kip242 I don't see where you're getting the `delete` value from the case in your post. Check that and that isn't failing somehow. Also, you appear to be missing a closing brace for this `foreach ($rows as $row) {`. That should be throwing a parse error.

Comment: I did not add that code to the question, but that is working.  The session variables are being carried around like they are supposed to, they are not being destroyed after I submit an update to text and go back to BEdisplay so I cannot select another project to update or delete, the session variables still reference the originally selected project